# QGIS invalid layer: Cannot open GDAL dataset / not recognised as a supported file format

Tags: qgis, gdal, geotiff-tiff

I am trying to add a raster dataset in QGIS and I get this message:

*Invalid layer
Cannot open GDAL dataset C:/Users/Nefel/Downloads/crm.tif:
`C:/Users/Nefel/Downloads/crm.tif' not recognised as a supported file format.*

The weird thing is, I have downloaded multiple datasets from the same site. Some of them work fine and with some I get this error.

The datasets were downloaded from here: 
https://maps.ngdc.noaa.gov/viewers/wcs-client/

Comment: I downloaded a file in ascii format and instead of an ascii file it downloaded a XML file hidden within the ascii file. I am sure, when you open your tif, with a text editor you will see the same. this must be an error on the server side. Maybe you could/should contact NOAA?

Comment: Just tested with an arbitrary rectangle over Europe and it works for me. Maybe a server hangup.